# Запись файла в нужной кодировке через file_put_contents()

Tags: php, кодировка, utf-8

Есть код:

```
$msg = htmlspecialchars($_POST['msg']);
$file = file('file.php');
$file[39] = " ".PHP_EOL."array_push(\$r, \"<font color=green>".$msg." 
</font>\");";
$fl = file_put_contents('file.php', $file);
if (!$fl) {
    echo "Ошибка!";
    exit;
}
```

Нужно что бы при перезаписи файла с изменением конкретной строки так же кодировка была не `UTF-8`, а `windows-1251`.

Была идея пропустить `$file` через `iconv`, но в таком случае выходит ошибка, а файл просто стирается

Comment: ну кодируйте скрипт в cp-1251

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно применить iconv к конкретной строке, а не к массиву строк.